# Ubuntu network issue after suspend

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, suspend, 19.04

I'm using an Ubuntu 19.04 with KDE environment. When I put Ubuntu in suspend mode and then awake it I have no network (wired and wi-fi as well). It seems that this problem once was somewhere on 4th version of Kernel and was fixed, however Ubuntu 19.04 is run on 5th version of Kernel (therefore supposedly containing the fix).

Is there anything I can do with drivers or updates to fix this problem?

I know that I can manually write a script that will restart both drivers but that doesn't seem to be a good solution (more like a workaround).